# Add column filter to Categories -> Products in category

Tags: magento2, php, grid, uicomponent

I was just wondering if it is possible to add the column filter here.
(So the filter that allows you to filter which columns are shown in the grid)

I notice this grid is not made up of UI components but is made programmatically trough PHP. Is there any way to add this?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways for adding the custom filters in the UI Component.

- By PHP
  Here is the link for adding filters by PHP.
  https://webkul.com/blog/magento2-multi-select-filter/
- BY UI Component
  Here is the link of adding the filters by UI Component by Xml.
  https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/ui_comp_guide/components/ui-filters.html